# Flattening lists without removing the tuples

Tags: python

How to flatten a nested list that contains tuples without removing the tuples?
 example:

```
flatten([1,2,3,(4,5,6),[7,8,9]]) 
[1, 2, 3, (4, 5, 6),7,8,9]
```

Comment: Take one of the [answers here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/952914/how-to-make-a-flat-list-out-of-list-of-lists) and add your own type checking. If something goes wrong, post a question asking for help.

Comment: (4,5,6) should be [4,5,6] if you want expected result

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why not simple loops:

```
>>> L = [1,2,3,(4,5,6),[7,8,9]]
>>> L2 = []
>>> for i in L:
    if isinstance(i,list):
        L2.extend(i)
    else:
        L2.append(i)


>>> L2
[1, 2, 3, (4, 5, 6), 7, 8, 9]
>>>
```

Comment: This only works for 1 layer of nesting though. But it does fit the question's criteria.

Answer (score 0):

```
def flatten(arr):
    if not isinstance(arr, list):
        return arr
    else:
        output = []
        for sy in arr:
            if isinstance(sy, list):
                temp = flatten(sy)
                for py in temp:
                    output.append(py)
            else:
                output.append(sy)
        return output

print (flatten([1,2,3,(4,5,6),[7,8,9]]))
#[1, 2, 3, (4, 5, 6), 7, 8, 9]
```

Answer (score 0):

Here a try :

```
f = lambda *n: (e for a in n
    for e in (f(*a) if isinstance(a, (list)) else (a,)))

print(list(f([1,2,3,(4,5,6),[7,8,9]])))
# [1, 2, 3, (4, 5, 6), 7, 8, 9]
```